# Accessing dnn 6 website on another pc using IP address

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, dotnetnuke, webmatrix

I have made a website in dnn version 6 and hosted it on local IIS server. When I am trying to access it on another pc by giving ip address and port it opens installation wizard of dotnetnuke. Following error is displayed on very first page of installation wizard.
"The Auto option has been disabled as the DotNetNuke Application cannot connect to a valid SQL Server database"

installation fails on database wizard page by giving connection error. I have also published database but it fails to find the file (I think).

I dont know why this happens because IIS is accessible on another pc and also other asp.net websites, there is also no problem with alias of the site.

Plz help me in solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

You problem is most likely with the database connection information stored in the web.config. Make sure the connection string information is valid. It may be the case that the particular server you've deployed to does not have access to the database server or database in question.

Example:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="SiteSqlServer" connectionString="Server=SERVERNAME;Database=DATABASENAME;uid=username;pwd=password;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The best way to test this is to take the information in the web.config and try to manually connect through SQL Server Management Studio. If the credentials don't work, there's your problem.